# Linq Limiting records gives error for paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create pagination my LINQ query gives error:

```
var query = from c in db.Projects.Take(2).Skip(2) orderby c.ProjectId descending select c;
```

gives the following error:

```
$exception  {"The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}
```

Comment: _The method 'OrderBy' must be called **before** the method 'Skip'_ should be obvious

Comment: Not everyone can read. Many that refuse reading still try programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var query = (from c in db.Projects orderby c.ProjectId descending select c).AsEnumerable().Skip(2).Take(2)
```

Or More efficient (Credit to Jon Skeet)

```
var query = (from c in db.Projects orderby c.ProjectId descending select c).Skip(2).Take(2)
```

Comment: Using `AsEnumerable` here means that the paging wouldn't be performed in the database - so if the OP were *actually* asking for records 1,000,000 to 1,000,009, it would fetch the first million records, only to throw them away.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed. However, is there a way then to actually perform using linq-to-sql query without this overhead?

Comment: Yes - just remove the `AsEnumerable` call.

Answer (score 4):

The error describes exactly what is required - your sequence needs to be ordered before skip/take many any sense. You already know what ordering you want - you've just got to make it happen earlier in the logical pipeline than the paging. Additionally, there's really no benefit in using a query expression here. I suggest you use:

```
var query = db.Projects
              .OrderByDescending(c => c.ProjectId)
              .Skip(2)
              .Take(2);
```

(That can all be in one line if you really want it to be, but I find it simpler to understand the pipeline if it's laid out vertically.)

Note that I've also inverted the order of `Skip` and `Take` - you almost *never* want `Take` before `Skip`... in your sample code, you've shown `Take(2).Skip(2)` which could never return any results... the result of the `Take(2)` part is a sequence with at most two results, and then the `Skip(2)` is skipping the first two of those results... leaving nothing. Typically you have something like:

```
.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)
```